# Cannot access the file server with just \\hostname in file explorer

Tags: windows-10, networking, active-directory, azure, windows-server-2022

I can access a server on the File Explorer only by fully qualified domain name, FQDN. Full story:

We have two domains, our company's domain, Apollo and the parent company's, Zeus.

We are running on local servers and the parent company has moved onto Azure. Therefore, we are slowly moving to Azure.

There is a trust  established between Azure and our AD.

We have a machine called ApolloServer, full name ApolloServer.Apollo.Aii. The idea is to remove ApolloServer from the Apollo domain. Make a vm in Azure with the same name so the name of the machine became ApolloServer.Zeus.Zii.

The ip of ApolloServer.Zeus.Zii is 10.40.20.11 (different from ApolloServer.Apollo.Aii). In DNS Manager we have Zeus.Zii set up as conditional forwarder.
I deleted the old A-record in the DNS Manager for ApolloServer and made a new A-record under the zone Apollo.Aii  with the name ApolloServer and pointed to the ip of the new machine 10.40.20.11. The A-Record entry now looks like: Host-ApolloServer, FQDN - ApolloServer.Apollo.Aii, IP - 10.40.20.11

Now, if user on the Apollo domain was to ping ApolloServer, it works, the result shows the reply was from ApolloServer.Apollo.Aii ip 10.40.20.11.  Yay!! Seems like all is well. But no and here is the issue.

From a machine on Apollo domain via File Explorer this server is reachable as \ApolloServer.Zeus.Zii and \10.40.20.11. It is not reachable as \ApolloServer.Apollo.Aii nor by \ApolloServer which very puzzling as ping shows the result I mentioned above. We want it to be accessible only bt \ApolloServer from the file explorer and as this is a file server and  some applications look only for \ApolloServer

I have tried editing the Host file on the users machine to 10.40.20.11 ApolloServer.Apollo.Aii but it doesn't work.